# Javascript - Is using destructuring and spread syntax more efficient than using pre-build functions?

Tags: javascript, performance, destructuring, spread-syntax

Reading MDN's documentation about destructuring I found it can reduce many lines of code containing assigments. With spread variables, this can be used in the same way than Haskell's pattern matching. For example, the three following functions are almost equivalent:

```
let tail' (x:xs) = xs -- Haskell
```

<sup>Exception when empty list is given as input</sup>

```
let tail = ([x,...xs])=>xs; // * Javascript [ECMAScript 6th ed.+]
```

```
let tail = (xs)=>xs.slice(1) // * Javascript [ECMAScript 3rd ed.+]
```

<sup>*An empty array is returned when an empty array is given as input</sup>

Here's another example of this:

```
let conc = (a1,a2)=>[...a1,...a2]; // returns the same than...
let conc = (a1,a2)=>a1.concat(a2);
```

Which is the most efficient implementation of `conc` function?

Comment: The performance difference will be negligible as both of them will use plain javascript logic to implement the concatenation. One case might have slightly more statements to execute but Javascript is pretty fast, so it's negligible and you need not worry about it.

Comment: you could benchmark it, but really, unless you're doing this in a loop of thousands or millions of iterations, you probably won't notice any difference